# JQuery Click Event Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to get a popup box to only load every 24 hours but I have no idea how to get the JQuery Click Event to accept/create cookies.  I am relativity new to this.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $('.ajax').click(); });
        // Create a cookie
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

        // Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 1 });

        // Read a cookie
        $.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
        $.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

        // EDIT
        // Attaching to a button click (jQuery 1.7+) and set cookie
        $("#ajax").on("click", function () {
            $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 1 });
        });

        // Attaching to a button click (jQuery < 1.7) and set cookie
        $("#ajax").click(function () {
            $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 1 });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a class='ajax' href="./content/ajax.html" title="Vote IG Top 100!"></a></p>
</body>
```

Here is the webpage:

http://iconik-gaming.com/popup/

Thanks everyone!

Comment: why write/check the cookie on click event?

make the check before you open the popup in $(document).ready(function(){ $(".ajax").colorbox(); });

Comment: I'm confused on how I would do that.  From some searches on Google the code looks ok but I'm not even 100% sure if its corrent.  Thanks for your help so far! @soderslatt

Comment: Note that `$.cookie` requires the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: Thanks, is there anything else I need to do one I have installed the plugin?  @MichaelMior

Comment: I added the plugin, updated index.php but it still does not work.